In gazebo, is it possible (as easy as possible) to add the camera sensor to the drone programmatically from plugin?
For our use case we need to add sensors (cameras, IMUs) programmatically at runtime in the running gazebo simulation. The sensors have to be relative to simulated vehicles (drones, rovers).
The idea is to implement gazebo plugin which will create the sensors at runtime whenever needed, without the need of the prepared SDFs.
We use Gazebo Classic 11 and the class descriptions found here: https://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/11.0.0/classes.html
Unfortunately, after several tries and fails we are not able to add the working camera sensor to the world, always some "links" are missing, added sensors are not found, we simply have all the problems because of lack of deeper knowledge of gazebo internals.
Is there a way how to add the WORKING sensors as described above? Many thanks in advance for any hints.
